# Error when installing TDA package on R

Tags: r, compiler-errors, package, installation

I'm trying install TDA package on R

```
> install.packages("TDA")
Installing package into ‘/home/more/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/TDA_1.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 2006514 bytes (1.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 MB
```

and I got this error

```
./gmpxx.h:41:17: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gmp.h>
           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [diag.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘TDA’
* removing ‘/home/more/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/TDA’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘TDA’ had non-zero exit status
```

Here's my sessionInfo

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

The installation on my windows 7 was without any error

What should I do to fix this problem??

Comment: is `gmp` installed?  `sudo yum install gmp`

Comment: Yes it's installed.

gmp-6.0.0-12.e17_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: what about `gmp-devel`?

Comment: Just installed now. 
And now the install process gave another error.

    #include <mpfr.h>
                                 ^
    compilation terminated.

Comment: OK after installed mpfr-devel the installation can be done.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on Fedora 23:

`sudo yum install gmp-devel mpfr-devel`

Comment: Just done this few mins ago. After installed mpfr-devel the installation can be done. Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 4):

I got around this issue on Ubuntu 16.04 with:

```
sudo apt install libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev
```