# error installing TDA in ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

I try to install TDA in R but I got error.

make: *** [diag.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘TDA’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/TDA’
Error in i.p(...) :

I try sudo yum install gmp-devel mpfr-devel
but ubuntu has  libgmp3-dev and libmpfr-dev installed

I also try :
install_version('TDA', version='1.4.1')

But I got the same error.

Thank in advance for any clue about how to fix.

Comment: working around error:     ‘next’ is not a member of ‘boost’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside TDA R source

/TDA/src/topology/rips.hpp

add:

`#include <boost/next_prior.hpp>`

the reason is "next" is no inside

```
<boost/utility.hpp>
```

anymore.