# TDA package for R fails to compile

Tags: r

I am trying to install the TDA package from CRAN. I'm on Arch Linux running R version 4.1.2. I get the following error.

> make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:177: diag.o] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘TDA’

I've tried the solutions in the three other posts about TDA.

[error installing TDA in ubuntu 18.04 bionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337984/error-installing-tda-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic)

[Error when installing TDA package on R: recipe for target 'diag.o' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646946/error-when-installing-tda-package-on-r-recipe-for-target-diag-o-failed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Error when installing TDA package on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628766/error-when-installing-tda-package-on-r)

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems were identified by low availability of memory... if you have 1gb machine try to increase the memory and gcc make probably will be ok.
The reference is here below.
https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-install-imager-on-rstudio-cloud-without-exceeds-memory-limit/130080